# `.firebase/hosting.記号.cache` を commit しなかった場合の影響は?

Tags: firebase

firebase の hosting にデプロイしました。すると、

```
.firebase/hosting.ABCZSW.cache
```

のようなファイルが生成されました。

中身を見てみると、次のような csv 形式になっています。

```
デプロイされたファイルのパス,timestamp,SHA-SUMのようなもの
```

#### 質問

- `.firebase/hosting.ABCXYZ.cache`ファイルは何のためにあるファイルですか?

  - これは .gitignore してよいものでしょうか。その場合の影響は何でしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/q/52130772/3090068 で同様の質問を行いました。結果として、

- 件のファイルは firebase deploy を高速化するためのファイル
- .firebase 以下はひとまず .gitignore で問題ない